# how should I limit the number of children a parent model can have in laravel

Tags: laravel

Lets say a parent model has a hasMany() relationship with a child model. How should I go about setting some arbitrary limit to the number of children it can have? Should I do so during validation? and if so how?

Comment: What you have tried? At least post some code

Comment: I thought maybe i could make a custom validation rule but that didn't seem like the right way

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function that return the actual number of children. And a second function to apply the logic you want based on the previous return.
For example, If you want to the parent model to only have 3 children, you have to check for the actual number of children and apply the logic before running your create and/or store functions.

You can also use Model Events in Observers to add your own logic while the model is completing or has completed some action. You can check the links below for more details.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/events

Comment: I'm not sure where to place my code. Right not all my validation is in a form request but the child limit has nothing to do with the form data so I'm not sure if it's a good place for it. It would be nice to be in the form request so everything can be in one place.

Comment: That said the nice way to do it is to create custom validation rule. So you can validate your data anywhere you need it. Let me provide you a link where it is well explained. 
https://laraveldaily.com/how-to-create-custom-validation-rules-laravel/